# React onClick, Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, frontend

I'm trying to run a  onclick function in react

My button:

```
<button onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)}>LogOut</button>
```

My function

```
function logOut(){
Auth.signOut()
.then(data => console.log(logout)
.catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

but the an error comes back Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: Try adding `this.logOut = this.logOut.bind(this);` in your constructor, and then replace the call by `{this.logOut}`

Comment: post the whole component, chances are you need to remove the keyword `function`

Comment: as @lustoykov: suggested `function` keyword is not required inside a class in ES6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, never bind in your render method. `bind` returns a new method each time you call it, which means that react cant optimise your render method. React looks at the props of components to see if anything has changed, and with functions, it compares equality by object reference. Since your function will be a new function each time, react will think things are changing.

Secondly, you can use an arrow function in your component to avoid the need for bind all together.

Here are two ways you can write this differently, first with bind:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.logOut = this.logOut.bind(this);
    }
    function logOut() {
        //...
    }
    function render() {
        return <button onClick={this.logOut}>LogOut</button>
    }
}
```

Secondly with an arrow function:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    logOut = () => {
        //...
    }
    function render() {
        return <button onClick={this.logOut}>LogOut</button>
    }
}
```

Comment: key info is "never bind in your render method"

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful if you can please give more details .

Just tried an example in codepen and I see it working fine. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKBdaB?editors=0011

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {


  handleClick() {
    console.log('Hello')
 }

render() {
 return (
  <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
   SayHello
  </button>
);
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```